# bypass validation rule on insert

Tags: validation

I have a validation rule:

```
(ISPICKVAL(Order.Type ,'SO Regular Sales Order ') && ( ISPICKVAL(Line_Type__c ,'NONE') || ISPICKVAL(Line_Type__c,'REC')))
```

I want to bypass the validation on insert and only fire the validation on edit if it meets the criteria. I tried using NOT(ISNEW()), but that didn't work. How can I bypass the insert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rule will look like this:

```
AND(
    NOT(ISNEW()),
    ISPICKVAL(Order.Type ,'SO Regular Sales Order'),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Line_Type__c ,'NONE'),
        ISPICKVAL(Line_Type__c,'REC')
    )
)
```

Also, I think I can see an extra space `'SO Regular Sales Order '` at the end of this picklist value type.